# How do I know, when a WPF tab control page was successfully selected?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

**What I want**

I need to select a tab in my tab control and scroll visually to a certain element.

My standard WPF tab control's ItemSource is bound to a collection of view models which have no reference to their corresponding view (standard MVVM pattern). There is also a binding for the tab control's SelectedItem property.

The view model of the required tab and the name of the target control are given as parameters.

**What I did**

When I open my window and the tab control is [Loaded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded?view=net-5.0), I navigate to the required tab by setting the SelectedItem property.  As a result, the correct tab page is displayed and I also get the desired [SelectionChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectionchanged?view=net-5.0) event on the [TabControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.tabcontrol?view=net-5.0#events).

Because I do not have references of my views in my view models, I need to walk down the visual tree to find the control I am looking for in order to bring it into view. When I print the entire visual tree of my tab control into a log file, it is clearly visible, that I get the visual tree of the *initial* tab page and *not* of the newly selected one. I was hoping to get a second [Loaded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded?view=net-5.0) event once the new tab page is loaded, but that did not happen.

**Question**

How do I know when my newly selected tab page is loaded so that I can walk down the correct visual tree?

**Code snippet**

This is the function I use for walking down the visual graph. I call it by providing my tab control as input parameter. I get the perfect visual tree, but from the initial page and not the newly selected one.

```
    public void FindVisualChildren(DependencyObject obj, string prefix = "")
    {
        if (obj != null)
        {
            var output = $"{prefix} obj = {obj}";

            if (obj is FrameworkElement frameworkElement && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(frameworkElement.Name))
                output += $", name = \"{frameworkElement.Name}\"";

            if (obj is TextBlock textBlock && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBlock.Text))
                output += $", text = \"{textBlock.Text}\"";

            if (obj is TextBox textBox && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text))
                output += $", text = \"{textBox.Text}\"";

            this.WarningWriteLine(() => output);

            for (var i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
            {
                var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);

                FindVisualChildren(child, prefix + "  ");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to pass the TabItem (or the SelectedItem property of the TabControl) instead of the TabControl to the FindVisualChildren function.

Comment: Hello Scott. When I use the Tab Control in my function I also get all tab items. The visual tree of the content of a tab page is in the Tab Control itself, not on the tab item. The visual tree of the tab item only contains the actual tab (caption etc.)

Answer (score 2):

The moment `TabControl.SelectionChanged` is raised the new content that relates to the `TabControl.SelectedItem` is loaded and ready for access.

You don't have to traverse the complete `TabControl` tree to get to the content elements. You can shorten traversal by starting traversal from the selected content's container:

```
// Handle TabControl.SelectionChanged routed event
private void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var tabControl = sender as TabControl;
  object selectedContentItem = tabControl.SelectedContent;
  
  // Visual tree root of content sub-tree
  var selectedContentItemConmtainer =
    tabControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(selectedContentItem);

  // Print sub-tree of currently selected content
  FindVisualChildren(selectedContentItemConmtainer);
}
```

### Alternative version

When using a single data model and then design the tab item and tab content using data templates, then the previous version won't help, as `TabControl.SelectedContent` and `TabControl.SelectedItem` are equal (in reference).

```
// Handle TabControl.SelectionChanged routed event
private void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var tabControl = sender as TabControl;
  
  // Visual tree root of content sub-tree
  var tabContentHost = tabControl.Template.FindName("PART_SelectedContentHost", tabControl) as ContentPresenter;

  // Print sub-tree of currently selected content
  FindVisualChildren(tabContentHost);
}
```

Comment: Thank you BionicCode, but your code did not work for me. I only get the content of the selected tab item using your code, but I need the content of the tab page. Even if I put the code into a lock to avoid run-time interferences, I still only get the visual tree of the initial tab when writing the entire tab control visual tree to a log file.

Comment: I have tested the code and it works. there is no chance to get the TabItem as we are accessing `tabControl.SelectedContent`, which will return the actual content of the tab and not the header (TabItem) like `tabControl.SelectedItem` would do. Can you please show how you setup your TabControl? Maybe we need to adjust to your different setup.

Comment: If your content binds to the same model that the item binds to, then of course both items are identical. Please check my alternative version of my updated answer and let me know if this helps.